# Change the font-size of price range on Woocommerce product pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the size of the font of the prices ranges down to 32px on my wordpress website woocommerce product pages (i.e. "£8.00-£20.00"), please see example page:

http://www.partisan-deli.co.uk/index.php/product/1723/

As far as I can tell there are at least two different css classes that make up the price range:

woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol
woocommerce-Price-amount amount

I have tried adding the relevant css to these classes separately in my style sheet but to no effect.

Does anyone know how I can change all of them all-together for the price range?

Cheers,

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this class that you have in your css:

```
.single-product .entry-summary .price span
```

add a `font-size: 32px;`

Comment: This looked like the most specifc/effecient solution to me...and it worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.price span {
 font-size: 32px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
    .price span{
font-size: 32px !important;
}


   .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount, .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol {
    font-size: 32px !important;
}
```

Thanks !!